# Pytest assert function called outside class

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a python script called reconciler.py which has code as below

```
from service.type.logger import getLogger

logger = getLogger()

class get_or_create_obj(model_class, is_new_asset, **kwargs):
    if is_new_asset:
        return model_class.objects.create(**kwargs)
    else:
        obj, created = model_class.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
        return obj
```

I need to write a test case which makes sure that getLogger is getting called. I tried this,

```
class TestLogger(MyTestCase):
    def test_logger(self):
        with patch("service.type.logger.getLogger") as logger:
            assert logger.called
```

But the result is false.

Please advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not calling the logger after you patch it - it has already been called on the import before it was patched.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen yeah, but how can I assert that?

Comment: You could reload the module (`importlib.reload()`) after you patch it.